# Field in table missing from insert statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When trying to create a new row (product), the INSERT statement generated by the create method is missing the product_type_id field that is declared NOT NULL. I can't figure out why Rails is not including the product_type_id field in the insert statement.

I get the following error when trying to save a product.

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin::ProductsController#create

Mysql2::Error: Field 'product_type_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `products` (`brand_id`, `created_at`, `description`, `image_base`, `media_embed`, `msrp`, `name`, `price_override`, `thumbnail_desc`, `updated_at`, `vendor_sku`, `year`) VALUES (9, '2014-08-31 16:45:50', '', 'a', 'b', 33.0, 'a', 3.0, '', '2014-08-31 16:45:50', '', 2015)

But, the products table has the product_type_id field:

```
desc products
--------------

+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_type_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| brand_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name            | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| thumbnail_desc  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year            | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vendor_sku      | varchar(30)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| msrp            | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price_override  | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| visible         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| available       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| image_base      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| video_source    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| media_embed     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
18 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

and the request parameters show the product_type_id and its value:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VT42eeLLT/pyQ05ycfU/PeK92LIQ1P7NpWcPDOuOvsg=",
 "product"=>{"year"=>"2015",
 "brand_id"=>"9",
 "name"=>"a",
 "description"=>"",
 "thumbnail_desc"=>"",
 "category_ids"=>["",
 "29"],
 "product_class_ids"=>[""],
 "image_base"=>"a",
 "media_embed"=>"b",
 "vendor_sku"=>"",
 "msrp"=>"33",
 "price_override"=>"3",
 "visible"=>"1",
 "available"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create Backpack",
 "product_type_id"=>"39"}
```

The Product Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :product_type

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :product_classes

  scope :sorted, lambda { order("name ASC") }
  scope :notdeleted, lambda { where(:deleted_at => nil) }

  def active
    deleted_at.nil?
  end

end
```

The ProductType Model:

```
class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :product_classes
  has_many :products

  validates_presence_of :name

  scope :sorted, lambda { order("name ASC") }
  scope :notdeleted, lambda { where(:deleted_at => nil) }

  def active
     deleted_at.nil?
  end

  def active=(val)
     self.deleted_at = [nil, '', '0', false].member?(val) ? Time.now : nil
  end

end
```

The :product_type_id symbol is declared in params.permit in the products controller:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController

  layout 'admin'

  before_action :confirm_logged_in
  before_action :get_product, only: [:edit, :update, :delete, :destroy]
  before_action :get_stuff,   only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :delete, :destroy]

  def index
    @product_types = ProductType.notdeleted.sorted
  end

  def show
    #redirect_to(:action => 'manage_products')
  end

  def new
    @product_type = ProductType.find(params[:product_type_id])
    @product = Product.new({:product_type_id => @product_type.id})
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Product created.'
      redirect_to(:action => 'index', :product_type_id => @product_type.id)
    else
      render("new")
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Product updated.'
      redirect_to(:action => 'manage_products', :product_type_id => @product_type.id)
    else
      render("edit")
    end
  end

  def delete
  end

  def destroy
    @product.update(deleted_at: Time.now, visible: 0, available: 0)
    flash[:notice] = "Product deleted."
    redirect_to(:action => 'manage_products', :product_type_id => @product_type.id)
  end

  def manage_products
    id = params[:product_type_id]
    @product_type = ProductType.find(id)

    if params[:include_deleted] 
      @products = @product_type.products.sorted
    else
      @products = @product_type.products.notdeleted.sorted
    end

    #logger.debug("The size of products is #{@products.size}")
  end

  private

    def get_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      logger.debug("The product type id is #{@product.product_type_id}")
      @product_type = ProductType.find(@product.product_type_id)
      logger.debug("The product type is #{@product_type.name}")
      logger.debug("The product type has price is #{@product_type.has_price}")
    end

    def get_stuff
      @brands = Brand.sorted
      @categories = Category.sorted
    end

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit( :product_type_id, :brand_id, :name, :thumbnail_desc, :description, :year, :vendor_sku,
     :msrp, :price_override, :visible, :available, :image_base, :media_embed, :active, 
     :category_ids => [], :product_class_ids => [])
  end

end
```

The new.html.erb

```
<% @page_title = "Create #{@product_type.name}" %>

<% content_for(:navigation) do -%>
    <p><a href="<%= admin_products_path %>"><img src="/assets/layout/icons/arrow_left.png" alt="Back" /> Back to <%= @product_type.name   %> List</a></p>
<% end -%>

<%= yield :navigation %>

  <%= form_for([:admin, @product], :url => {:action => 'create', :product_type_id => @product_type.id}) do |form| %>

  <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:form => form} %>

  <div class="form-buttons">
    <%= submit_tag("Create #{@product_type.name}") %>
  </div>

  <% end %>

<%= yield :navigation %>
```

And finally, the _form.html.erb

```
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved:</h2>
       <%= error_messages_for(@product) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="admintable">
   <tr> 
    <th>Year</th>
    <td><%= form.text_field :year, :size => 5 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <td><%= form.select(:brand_id, @brands.map {|b| [b.name, b.id]}) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <td><%= form.text_field :name, :size => 30 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <th>Description</th>
    <td><%= form.text_area :description, :cols => 60, :rows => 30 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <th>Thumbnail Description</th>
    <td><%= form.text_area :thumbnail_desc, :cols => 60, :rows => 5 %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <th>Categories</th>
    <td>
    <%= form.collection_select :category_ids, Category.sorted, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, include_blank: true, :size => 20 } %>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr> 
    <th>Product Class</th>
    <td>
    <%= form.collection_select :product_class_ids, ProductClass.options_for_select(@product.product_type_id), :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, include_blank: true, :size => 4 } %>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr> 
    <th>Image Base</th>
    <td><%= form.text_field :image_base, :size => 40 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr> 
    <th>Media Embed Code</th>
    <td><%= form.text_area :media_embed, :cols => 60, :rows => 5 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr> 
    <th>Vendor SKU</th>
    <td><%= form.text_field :vendor_sku, :size => 30 %></td>
  </tr>

  <% if @product_type.has_price? -%>
  <tr> 
    <th>MSRP</th>
    <td><%= form.text_field :msrp, :size => 5 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr> 
    <th>BW Price</th>
    <td><%= form.text_field :price_override, :size => 5 %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end -%>

  <tr>
    <th>Visible?</th>
    <td><%= form.check_box :visible %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Available?</th>
    <td><%= form.check_box :available %></td>
  </tr>

  <% unless @product.active -%>
  <tr>
    <th>Active</th>
    <td><%= form.check_box :active %></td>
  </tr>

  <% end -%>

</table>
```

Comment: You should start with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - there is a lot of extraneous information here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the missing field into the insert statement, I had to include the value in the form and hide it:

```
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved:</h2>
       <%= error_messages_for(@product) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%= form.hidden_field :product_type_id, :value => @product_type.id %>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="admintable">
   <tr> 
    <th>Year</th>
    <td><%= form.text_field :year, :size => 5 %></td>
  </tr>
```

I also added this line to the beginning of the create method:

```
    @product_type = ProductType.find(params[:product_type_id])
```

Thank you Alex, for getting me on the right track.

Comment: Rails takes the fields from the form when creating the insert statement instead of from the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reorder product_type id like this:

```
"price_override"=>"3",
"visible"=>"1",
"available"=>"1",
"product_type_id"=>"39"},
"commit"=>"Create Backpack"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Where in the application do I specify the order of the parameters?

Comment: If I'm not completely mistaken it should be in: ````Request/Parameters````

Comment: I tried using a hidden field in the form, so that that the parameters looked like this in the trace:

Comment: Request
    
    Parameters:
    
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"VT42eeLLT/pyQ05ycfU/PeK92LIQ1P7NpWcPDOuOvsg=",
     "product"=>{"year"=>"2015",
     "brand_id"=>"9",
     "name"=>"a",
     "description"=>"b",
     "thumbnail_desc"=>"c",
     "category_ids"=>["",
     "29"],
     "product_class_ids"=>[""],
     "image_base"=>"d",
     "media_embed"=>"e",
     "vendor_sku"=>"f",
     "msrp"=>"33",
     "price_override"=>"5",
     "visible"=>"1",
     "available"=>"1"},
     "product_type_id"=>"39",
     "commit"=>"Create Backpack"} but I still got the same error.